# Add content type machine name to an attribute in the body tag?

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

I figured this would be easily done in the [template_preprocess_html](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) function, but I haven't found a way to do it... yet.

I need to add the content type machine name to a "data-init" attribute in the body tag.  How can this be done exactly?

End result: `<body ... data-init="content_type">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`template_preprocess_html` should be the right function to start with.

So your code should look like the following:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    $variables['attributes_array']['data-init'][] = drupal_html_class('node-type-' . $node->type);
  }
}
```

Make sure to replace `mytheme` with your custom theme and clear Drupal cache.